# php associative array name?

Tags: php, associative-array

Just trying to get the name of an assoc array;

```
$test = array('selected' =>$selected, 'sectionList'=>$sectionList, 'categoryList'=>$categoryList);
<? foreach($test as $list) { ?>
<h3><?=$list?>, <?=$list[id]?>, <?=$list['name']?>, <?=$list['value']?></h3>
<? } ?>
```

but either get 'Array' or nothing?! I can see the name when i print_r($test);

Do you think this is possible? Thanks in advance, D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the syntax `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` to also get the key when iterating an array.

Answer (score 1):

try using :

foreach ( $test as $name => $list )

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array('selected' =>$selected, 'sectionList'=>$sectionList, 'categoryList'=>$categoryList);
    <? foreach($test as $key => $list) { ?>
        <? foreach($list as $list2) { ?>
            <h3><?=$key?>, <?=$list2[id]?>, <?=$list2['name']?>, <?=$list2['value']?></h3>
        <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
```